# Are running threads killed when an app exits?

Tags: multithreading, dart, flutter

If I have an `async` function that persists data for my **Flutter** app and it may take a second to finish, can I be sure that it will never be killed if the application is closed normally (i.e. no crash etc.)?

Comment: if u want sure never be killed 
create a service in your project that have a  async and handle it inside service also u can use it when user exited this app and your program stil running as well

Comment: It's currently not possible to run Dart code from a service afaik.

Comment: @ Elias Projahn you want " be sure that it will never be killed" i just say use Service in background and handle your exceptoon

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is dispose all of your controllers on

```
dispose();
```

Method